# AAD graph permission exception with Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AadV2Bot sample

Tags: botframework

I have the V3 **Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AadV2Bot** sample partly working.  I can retrieve info about the current user (`me.DisplayName` for example) so I know I have the basic configuration of AAD correct but when the code tries to get the user's manager it throws an exception that says, *"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"*.

I have added all kinds of permissions to the app's *Microsoft Graph Permissions* as *Delegated Permissions* and also added those same permissions to the Web App Bot's *OAuth Connection Settings* as: `email Mail.Read offline_access openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Directory.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All Group.Read.All People.Read People.Read.All Reports.Read.All User.Read.All`
… but it still gets the same error.

What I have not been able to do is to get the app to ask me again for the new permissions I added subsequent to giving the initial permissions when I first logged in so I don't know if that is an issue.

So my questions are:

1. What permission do I need to set to get a user's manager
2. Do I need to do anything to get the permission re-recognized.

The code that fails is below and its straight from the sample app with a try/catch added so I could see what was going on.  The exception (*"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"*) is thrown on the following line:

```
manager = await graphClient.Me.Manager.Request().GetAsync() as User;
```

Here is the full method in question with the above line included:

```
public async Task<User> GetManager()
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
    User manager = null;

    try
    {
        graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
        manager = await graphClient.Me.Manager.Request().GetAsync() as User;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string message = e.Message;
    }

    return manager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you need `User.ReadBasic.All` permission enabled.  Here is a few things to double check and/or try.

Make sure you have these scopes added to your bot's settings:

`OpenId` `email` `Mail.Send.Shared` `Mail.Read` `profile` `User.Read` `User.ReadBasic.All`

[image: scopes]

Also make sure you have added them to your AADv2 app on the apps.dev.microsoft.com site:

[image: App Permissions]

If you have already done these things try signing out and signing back in by typing "signout":

[image: Signout]

I have this working with these settings so I assume it should work for you as well.